# Can bash be used to communicate directly with hardware?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am interested in writing my own tool in bash to act in place of my current network controller (wpa_supplicant) if possible. For example if I want to issue commands in order to begin a wps authentication session with a router's external registrar, is it possible, without using any pre-built tools, to communicate with the kernel to directly access the hardware? I have been told that I can achieve what I desire with a bash [plugin](https://github.com/taviso/ctypes.sh) called `ctypes.sh` but I am not too certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the Linux kernel can interact with user-space through the following mechanisms:

- Syscalls
- Devices in `/dev`
- Entries in `/sys`
- Entries in `/proc`

Syscalls cannot be directly used from Bash but you need at least a binding through a C program.

You can create a Linux kernel driver or module which reads/writes data in an entry under `/proc` or `/sys` and then use a bash program to interact with it. Even if technically feasible, my personal opinion is that it is an overkill, and the usual C/C++ user-level programming with proper entries in `/dev` is much better.

Comment: Thanks you answered my question 100%. But that overkill and requirement of the use of C/C++ is why I included the plugin as a possible way to reduce the overkill. I'll most likely end up using c++ but the question was just a curiosity of mine.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is generally not possible. Shell scripts can mess around in /proc, but they don't have the ability to perform arbitrary IOCTLs or even multi-step interactive IO. It's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Would this also be the answer if I have the ctypes.sh plugin which allows me to script in C code inside of a bash script?